# karate gatling name resolver

Tags: karate

I have two scenarios in my feature file

```
@name=foo @name=fooRamp
Scenario : verify Performance for foo
Given def query = read('classpath:perf/testData/foo.graphql')
And request {query:'#(query)'}
And header karate-name = 'foo','fooRamp'

@name=bar @name=barRamp

Scenario : verify Performance for bar
Given def query = read('classpath:perf/testData/bar.graphql')
And request {query:'#(query)'}
And header karate-name = 'bar,'barRamp'
```

Two scenario I defined are

val scenario1=scenario("singleusers").exec(karateFeature("classpath:perf/foobar.feature@name=foo"))
.pause(3)
.exec(karateFeature("classpath:perf/foobar.feature@name=bar"))

val scenario2=scenario("ramp10Usersin30secs").exec(karateFeature("classpath:perf/foobar.feature@name=fooRamp"))
.pause(3)
.exec(karateFeature("classpath:perf/foobar.feature@name=barRamp"))

setUp(
scenario1.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(protocol),
scenario2.inject(rampUsers(10) during (30 seconds)).protocols(protocol)
)
What I get is

```
Request users metrics
foo     11     <responseTime>
bar     11     <responseTime>
```

I want to see in my report like

```
Request users metrics
foo     1     <responseTime>
bar     1     <responseTime>
fooRamp 10    <responseTime>
barRamp 10    <responseTime>
```

Is there any way that this can happen that I get separate names for single and ramp runs? Can nameresolver pick the different name for same feature scenario as per the scenario run in simulation? or do I need to create a duplicate scenario to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the logic after re-reading your question, so just do whatever conditional code you need and set a single header. Setting comma-delimited values won't work, it will take only the first.

```
* def temp = doSomeLogicHere()
And header karate-name = temp
```

There are multiple ways you can do the logic, look at the `karate.info` property, maybe looking at the feature name may give you what you need.

Comment: i want to reuse my scenario in feature file once for single user inject and then for ramp user load, but want it to come with a different name in request section of gatling report, and because of using name resolver is set to be karate-name. I can set only one name per scenario. I thought of making use of .header() in scenario setup but that won't work. Only karate.Feature() was working.

Comment: @avivohra no idea what you are saying. so follow this process, or wait for someone else to help you: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue